# RSS widget doesn't sync properly

Tags: rss, blogger, feed

I'm trying to integrate a feed on a blogger website but the RSS widget doesn't sync properly.

Feed link: http://www.centronoticias.pt/feed/

I tried also on a WordPress and the problem persists. I tested with Feedly and it is working and synchronized properly.

Someone as an idea where is the problem!?

Comment: Can you add the code you're using for integrate this RSS?

Comment: I'm using the RSS widget provided by blogger!

Comment: Open a new tab in your browser and press F12 key. Check the "network" and "console" tabs and see if there are errors. there is not enough information in your question for try debug this problem.

Comment: I checked the console and there are no errors. Anyway the problem is gone and I have no clue that what happened... Very strange!